# I can't write to the firestore database

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add name and price values to the list but with this function:

```js
Write_date () {
  alert ("write date");
   this.products.id = this.randomId();
db.collection("products").add(this.products)

.then(function(docRef) {

    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    this.products.name ="";
    this.products.price ="";

})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: an array"

The packages used on the vue js site are:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.13.0",
"core-js": "^3.6.4",
"firebase": "^7.14.2",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
"node-ipc": "^9.1.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"run": "^1.4.0",
"serve": "^11.3.0",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-fire": "^0.1.0",
"vue-router": "^3.1.6",
"vue-simple-alert": "^1.1.1"
```

```js
products: [],


   product: {
       name: null,
       price: null
    },

   fields: ['name', 'price'],
```

The support structure is the following:

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem.  You can't pass an array to `add()`.

Answer (score 0):

A Firestore document consists of named fields, each of which has a value. The value can be an array, but it must always be stored in a named field. And since you're passing an array without a name, the SDK rejects the operation.

---

If you're trying to add each product to the database as a separate document, that'd be:

```
this.products.forEach((product) {
  db.collection("products").add(product);
});
```

---

If you're trying to add all products to a single document, you must specify the name of the field to put the products in:

```
db.collection("products").add({ products: this.products });
```